# Why can I assign a value of int that is out of its range?

Tags: c, int

So I was trying to find the largest and 2nd largest integer in an array. So I assisnged it to be the smallest value possible and it seems like it can go below -(2^31).

I tried with value as large as -2^63 and it still work

```
void findMax1Max2(int m[], int size, int *max1, int *max2)
{
    int i;

    *max1 = -2147483648;
    *max2 = -2147483648;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (m[i] > *max1){
            *max2 = *max1;
            *max1 = m[i];
        }
        else if (m[i] > *max2){
            *max2 = m[i];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This behavior is entirely platform-specific.

Comment: And out of curiosity, did you enable pedantic warnings and warnings-as-errors when you compiled this with out-of-range values?

Comment: The compiler should warn you if the constant would overflow the representation.

Comment: Not answering the question, but use INT_MIN to do this.  This is defined in limits.h.

Comment: you need to look at where the 'm[]' parameter is being set.  in reality, the m[] value has to be in the valid int range.  so the problem (and you should have all warnings, etc enabled in the compile step) is in the caller, not in this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to get the smallest integer value is

```
#include <limits.h>

int val = INT_MIN;
```

Regarding your question you should read this [blog post](http://www.hardtoc.com/archives/119) explaining why INT_MIN is defined as `-2147483647 - 1` instead of `-2147483648`.